# Referencing Service.Name crashes after moving service code to ancestor

Tags: windows, delphi, service

I had a unit for a Windows (32 bit) service that was built up like this:

```
unit uSvcBase;

interface

type
  TMyServiceBase = class(TService)
    procedure ServiceBeforeUninstall(Sender: TService);
    procedure ServiceCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ServiceStop(Sender: TService; var Stopped: Boolean);
    procedure ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
    procedure ServiceStart(Sender: TService; var Started: Boolean);
    procedure ServiceAfterInstall(Sender: TService);
  private
  public
    function GetServiceController: TServiceController; override;
  end;

var
  MyServiceBase: TMyServiceBase;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}
{$R SvcEventLogMessages.res}

procedure ServiceController(CtrlCode: DWord); stdcall;
begin
  MyServiceBase.Controller(CtrlCode);
end;

function TMyServiceBase.GetServiceController: TServiceController;
begin
  Result := ServiceController;
end;

const
  rsServiceMessages =
  'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Application';

procedure TMyServiceBase.ServiceAfterInstall(Sender: TService);
var
   lReg    : TRegistry;
   lAppName: String;
begin
  lReg := TRegistry.create;
  try
    with lReg do
    begin
      Rootkey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
      if OpenKey(rsServiceMessages, False) then
        begin
          if OpenKey(MyServiceBase.Name, True) then
            begin
              lAppName := ParamStr(0);
              WriteString('EventMessageFile', lAppName);
              WriteString('CategoryMessageFile', lAppName);
              WriteInteger('CategoryCount', 2); 
              WriteInteger('TypesSupported', EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE OR EVENTLOG_WARNING_TYPE OR EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE);
              CloseKey;
            end;
          CloseKey;
        end; { if OpenKey }
    end; { with lReg }
  finally
    lReg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Because I needed to make a second service which was largely identical, I decided to make this a 'base' unit that others derive from (you can already see that in the names above):

```
unit uSvcTasks;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, uSvcBase;

type
  TMyServiceScheduler = class(TMyServiceBase)
    procedure ServiceCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
  end;

var
  MyServiceScheduler: TMyServiceScheduler;

implementation

{%CLASSGROUP 'System.Classes.TPersistent'}

{$R *.dfm}

Uses uTypesAlgemeen;

procedure TMyServiceScheduler.ServiceCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   inherited;
   // Set some properties
end;
```

At design time, the `MyServiceScheduler.Name` in this descendant differs from the `MyServiceBase.Name`.

**Issue**: The AfterInstall now crashed. Trying to use the original code using `OpenKey(MyServiceBase.Name` was not allowed.

I worked around his by using a property for the name (setting it in the descendant Create), but I do not understand why referencing `MyServiceBase.Name` in the AfterInstall does not work. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Uwe Raabe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26833/uwe-raabe)'s comments I was able to figure out how to fix this:

The project had an `Application.CreateForm(TMyServiceScheduler, MyServiceScheduler)` in the project source which initializes `MyServiceScheduler`, but there was nothing initializing `MyServiceBase`, so refering to it was illegal.

1. Replace the reference to `MyServiceBase.Name` with `Name` in the AfterInstall
   (That should've been done anyway).
2. Move the code for the ServiceController from `uSvcBase` to `uSvcTasks`